# Decrypt a message which is encrypted using XOR?

Tags: cryptanalysis, one-time-pad, xor

This is a puzzle asked in a contest. Given that encryption , decryption happens as per following rule/code:

```
    Encrypt(PlainTextBytes, KeyBytes){ 
        for(int i = 0;i < PlainTextBytes.length; i++) { 
            Cipherbytes[i] = PlainTextBytes[i] ^ KeyBytes[i]; 
        } 
        return Cipherbytes; 
    } 

    Decrypt(Cipherbytes, Keybytes){ 
        for(int i = 0; i < Cipherbytes.length; i++) { 
            Plaintextbytes[i] = Cipherbytes[i] ^ Keybytes[i]; 
        } 
        return Plaintextbytes; 
    } 

    Send(message){ 
        key=Read from file "SymmetricKey.txt" 
        Convert key to keyBytes and message to messageBytes using ASCII encoding 
        print "Message to be sent: ", encrypt(messagebytes, keybytes) 
    } 

    Receive(receivedmessage){ 
        key = Read from file "SymmetricKey.txt" 
        Convert key to keyBytes and receivedmessage to receivedmessageBytes using ASCII encoding 
        print "Message for you : " , decrypt(receivedmessagebytes, keybytes) 
    }
```

Given 3 encrypted message sequences as follows

```
    120, 84, 25, 1, 15, 17, 42, 21, 9, 12, 3, 49, 8, 29, 82, 31, 87, 118, 88, 92, 93 

    125, 87, 44, 7, 31, 41, 6, 8, 17, 51, 14, 17, 42, 27, 86, 19, 66, 92, 88, 86, 7 

    123, 84, 16, 28, 9, 10, 4, 2, 31, 55, 7, 6, 13, 61, 91, 62, 89, 91, 83, 87, 86
```

Some one has discovered that there is some flaw in encryption. IMO flaw doesn't lie with code it's in `Cipherbytes`. `Cipherbytes` may be having some patterns so that we can decrypt this message.

Is there a way I could get the source message of these three encrypted messages?

I have look at [How does one attack a two-time pad (i.e. one time pad with key reuse)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse?lq=1)
That question is different from this since that assumed that cipher text uses same pattern to encrypt in this case it's not true . I wrote simple program to test nothing prints on output.

as

```
char a1[ ]={120, 84, 25, 1, 15, 17, 42, 21, 9, 12, 3, 49, 8, 29, 82, 31, 87, 118, 88, 92, 93 };
     char a2[ ]={125, 87, 44, 7, 31, 41, 6, 8, 17, 51, 14, 17, 42, 27, 86, 19, 66, 92, 88, 86, 7};
     char a3[ ]={123, 84, 16, 28, 9, 10, 4, 2, 31, 55, 7, 6, 13, 61, 91, 62, 89, 91, 83, 87, 86 };

    for(i=0;i<256;i++){
            for(int l=0;l<22;l++){
                s1[l] =  (a1[l]^i)^a2[l];
                s2[l] =  (a1[l]^i)^a3[l];
            }
            flag=1;
            for(k=0;k<22;k++){
                if(s1[k]!=s2[k])flag=0;
            }
            if(flag){
               for(int k=0;k<22;k++){
                cout<<(s1[k]^a1[k]^a2[k])<<" ";
              }
              cout<<"\n";
            }
    }
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about debugging some code.

Comment: "flow" or "flaw"? As your question as been deemed off-topic, I suggest you look at the help-center to see what types of questions we expect here. BTW, welcome to the site.

Comment: @Gilles you don't have to debug this code . We have to find message with regard to given 3 sequence.

Comment: So just to be clear, there is no debugging of the code. The flaw is in the cipher. And you are wondering how to get the plaintexts given the three ciphertexts, correct?

Comment: Assuming KeyBytes and PlainTextBytes are the same length, then this is basically reusing a one-time-pad. We have had a number of questions on here related to that [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse) and [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse?lq=1)

Comment: @mikeazo Yes ,  I would like to get plain text.

Comment: Look over the two I linked to (especially the second). If it doesn't answer your question, feel free to edit and explain why and I'll reopen.

Comment: It seems that http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22710/553 has the same problem as you?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes both are same .